# How to make match function work for numeric value also

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I wrote the following code to copy the values.

```
valueName.forEach((item, idx) => {
      if (item.match(selectedName)) {
          let number = item.split('_').pop();
          if (Number(number) > count)
              count = Number(number) + 1;
          else
              count++;
      }
 });
 selectedName = selectedName + "_" + count;
```

It is working fine for string values of `selectedName` like abc, test etc. But if user enters numeric value like 1, 2 etc. then I am getting `item.match is not a function` error. 1

Comment: why don't you convert the numeric value to string? Would that serve your purpose?

Comment: `item.toString()`